# How to capture image from webcam in base64 in Angular2?

Tags: angular, base64, webcam

I am displaying the users webcam in an Angular2 app (latest version) using:

```
nav.getUserMedia(
        {video: true},
        (stream) => {
            let webcamUrl = URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            // 4a. Tell Angular the stream comes from a trusted source
            this.videosrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(webcamUrl);

            // 4b. Start video element to stream automatically from webcam.
            this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('video').autoplay = true;
        },
        (err) => console.log(err));
```

and in the template:

```
<video [src]="videosrc"></video>
```

This all works fine, but how do i capture the base64 image data being displayed to post to a server?